# Keep Angular material AutoComplete always open on focus

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular17

I'm using Angular material's [AutoComplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) as follows

```
    <form class="form">
        <mat-form-field class="search-user">
            <mat-label>User</mat-label>
            <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="userCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                @if(userCtrl.value?.length < 3) { 
                    <div class>Type 3 or more characters</div>
                } @else if(isLoading) {
                    <div>loading...</div>
                } @else if (!(filteredOptions | async)?.length) {
                    <div class>No match found</div>
                }
                @for (option of filteredOptions | async; track option) {
                    <mat-option [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
                    }
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

This is more or less a copy-past from one of their examples.

But what I would like to add is text above the options (inside the overlay) if there are no options (yet)

```
@if(userCtrl.value?.length < 3) { 
    <div class>Type 3 or more characters</div>
} @else if(isLoading) {
    <div>loading...</div>
} @else if (!(filteredOptions | async)?.length) {
    <div class>No match found</div>
}
```

However, the overlay is closed when there are 0 options. Is there a way, such that I can show/activate the overlay when the input has focus and 0 options (empty array)? But when the user select an options, the focus is lost and the overlay closes

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zyb8zj?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.scss,angular.json&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: you can use `@empty` along with `@for` when the array has no data in it...

Comment: it seems that when there are no results the overlay is gets hidden

Comment: I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zyb8zj?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.scss,angular.json&title=Angular%20Starter) for this

Comment: I noticed I can fake it by using the first option as a dummy, like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wfip2i?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.scss,angular.json&title=Angular%20Starter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use disabled `<mat-option>` elements (might need to play around with the `*ngIf` conditions to get exactly the right behavior):

```
<form class="form">
    <mat-form-field class="search-user">
        <mat-label>User</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="userCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
            <mat-option disabled *ngIf="userCtrl.value?.length < 3">Type 3 or more characters</mat-option>
            <mat-option disabled *ngIf="isLoading">Loading...</mat-option>
            <mat-option disabled *ngIf="(filteredOptions | async)?.length === 0">No match found</mat-option>
            <ng-container *ngIf="userCtrl.value?.length >= 3">
                <mat-option *ngFor="option of filteredOptions | async; track option" [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
            </ng-container>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```